# JQuery Ajax call - parameter from variable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have another problem :( 
I have WS, wchich is a part of VS 2010 MVC app. I can call it, and it works fine. 
My problem is, that I can't pass params from variables (function parameters)

```
function test2(usr, art) {
    alert('start : ' + usr);

    var params = {user : usr, idArt : art}

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/../WebServicePrzeczytany.asmx/Przeczytany",
        data: params,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function suc(msg) {
            alert("odebrane: ");
        },
        faild: fail
    });

    alert('stop : ' + art);
};
```

I'm calling it from button (for test). Any sugestions ?

PROBLEM SOLVED :

Again big thanks to  Anthony Grist (see comments), for Firebug. It's a powerful tool.

So, Firebug told my, that I'm getting error form WS. It was :  "Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in "/Przeczytany"".

The solution is to add

```
<webServices>
<protocols>
<add name="HttpGet"/>
<add name="HttpPost"/>
</protocols>
</webServices>
```

to the WS. And that's all.
jupi !! :)

Comment: end your var line with semicolon ;

Comment: @EnterJQ That's not a requirement in JavaScript.

Comment: What *does* happen? Use your browser's developer tools (Firebug in Firefox) to see if the request is sent, and to check for any JavaScript errors.

Comment: AJAX call is valid ( except for `faild` field - you probably wanted `error`? ). It looks like you have a problem on the server side.

Comment: Anthony Grist you are the greatest :) I didn't know Firebug. I used to work with IE Developers tools.
So, Firebug said that my WS throw an exception (or error): "Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in "/Przeczytany"" any sugestions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable JSON for your web service (by decorating the method with the `[ScriptService]` attribute) you will be able to invoke it like this:

```
function test2(usr, art) {
    alert('start : ' + usr);

    var params = {user : usr, idArt : art}

    $.ajax({
        // TODO: never hardcode an url like that => use an url helper to generate that!
        url: '/../WebServicePrzeczytany.asmx/Przeczytany',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function suc(msg) {
            alert('odebrane: ');
        },
        error: fail
    });

    alert('stop : ' + art);
};
```

Things to notice:

- usage of the `JSON.stringify` native method to convert the javascript object into a JSON string before passing it to the web service
- Setting `contentType: 'application/json'` because that's what we are passing to the service

Left for you to do:

- Replace the hardcoded url property to your service with an url generated from an url helper (such as `@Url.Content("~/WebServicePrzeczytany.asmx/Przeczytany")`).